# Find where int or string matches in array

Tags: arrays, ruby, search

Is there any way where I can not only find out if an array includes something but also where in the array it is found?

For example

finding `1` in `[1,4,6,4,1]` would return `[0,4]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `each_index` along with `select`:

```
arr = [1,4,6,4,1]
arr.each_index.select { |i| arr[i] == 1 }
#=> [0, 4]
```